# Why is FromOADate getting day and month wrong way round?

Tags: c#, excel

I have the date in an excel file "03/07/2013"

When I use the `DateTime.FromOADate()`  `Microsoft.Excel.Interop` method in my project to read this back  I am getting the date back as `"07/03/2013"`.

Have had a look at the other answers relating to this on stack overflow, none of which seem to solve this problem for me.

Comment: is july 3 or march 7 the right date?

Comment: can you not `format the date` to be in the format you are looking for as well as tying some `Date Parse` functions / methods to validate that it's a correct date. based on that date the `MM/DD || DD/MM` portion would still yield a correct date.. we need more information here from your end

Comment: My apologies. The correct date should be July 3rd

Comment: Somewhere, somehow, a string morphed into a DateTime.  Find the code that does that and you'll have a shot at fixing the bug.  We can't find it for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Excel is set to display day month year and your c# program is set to display month day year.

or, the opposite of that.

Change the display format of the one you don't like.

Comment: Thanks for that Eric. Turns out it was needed to be changed in the program with the spreadsheet using UK formatting.

Comment: You're welcome. I note that you made your question harder to answer by presupposing an answer in the question. Fromoadate has nothing to do with the fact that excel is configured to the sensible UK date format.

Comment: Agreed. Will be more careful in how I phrase the question in future.